# custom validators for angular 2 nested model-driven forms

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form whereby forms are nested within using ngFor. I need to validate a bank account number based on the bank name where it can be different for each form. The issue I am having seems to validate the bank account number for one form instance only.

Custom validator

```
  ValidateBankAccountNumber(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (this.ddGroup.controls) {
        const bankName = this.ddGroup.controls['bank'].value;
        if (bankName === "") {
          return { noBank: true };
        }
        const bankAcNo: string = control.value;
        if (bankName === 'MBC-01' && bankAcNo.length !== 12) {
          return { wrongMCBAcc: true };
        } 
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Based on the payment method, validators will be updated as per below

```
modeControlChanges$.subscribe(mode => {
  if (mode === 'DD') {
    //loop through each control of the formgroup and set validators accordingly
    Object.keys(formDdGroup.controls).forEach(key => {

      if (key === "bankNo" && modeTypeControl.value === "AD") {
        formDdGroup.controls[key].setValidators([Validators.required, this.ValidateBankAccountNumber.bind(this)]);
      }

      formDdGroup.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: could you please create working sample?

Comment: Please provide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: will try to put up a plunker asap. Thanks